# Error during getting android Bluetooth device RSSI from Windows 10 using BlueCove library

Tags: java, bluetooth, rssi, bluecove

I have the following simple code (below) using BlueCove 2.1.1 in particular the RemoteDeviceHelper.readRSSI(device) method which gives an error that so far I could not resolve. May I kindly ask your opinion? I'm trying a desktop app on Windows 10, and have a feeling that BlueCove wont work with this Windows version, or no other clue.

Here is the code:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    try {
        LocalDevice localDevice = LocalDevice.getLocalDevice();
        DiscoveryAgent discoveryAgent = localDevice.getDiscoveryAgent();

        // Discover nearby devices
        RemoteDevice[] devices = discoveryAgent.retrieveDevices(DiscoveryAgent.PREKNOWN);

        for (RemoteDevice device : devices) {
            System.out.println("Name: "+device.getFriendlyName(false));
            System.out.println("Address: "+device.getBluetoothAddress());

            // Get the RSSI value
            int rssi = RemoteDeviceHelper.readRSSI(device);
            System.out.println("Device: " + device.getBluetoothAddress() + ", RSSI: " + rssi);
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

This is the error I got:
[image]

Comment: The error message is clear. This function is not available on your system.

Comment: @Risto I would appreciate any comments on how to overcome this issue.

Comment: Have you considered that there may be no solution to this problem other than changing your operating system?